# Did Sommerfeld derive or measure the fine structure constant the first time he introduced it?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-theory

I used Wikipedia to try to figure this out but I am not clear on the explanation.  As for Newton's Law of Gravitation does not give the value for the Gravitational constant but it was measured by Cavendish.

I am wondering how the derivation was put together to arrive at the fine structure constant given that the units all cancel out or perhaps Sommerfeld calculated it's value.

Answer (score 4):

Computed (as $\alpha=e^2/\hbar c$) in equation [(12a), p. 51](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?u=1&id=umn.31951d003144537&num=51) of: Zur Quantentheorie der Spektrallinien, *Ann. Physik* (4) **51** (1916) 1–94.

(Earlier he had used $\alpha = (e^2/2\hbar c)^2$ in equation [(16), p. 469](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?u=1&id=uc1.b3976519&num=469) of Die Feinstruktur der Wasserstoff- und der Wasserstoff-ähnlichen Linien, *Münch. Ber.* **1915** (1916) 459–500. For discussion see e.g. M. Eckert (ed.) *Die Bohr-Sommerfeldsche Atomtheorie*, Springer ([2013](//doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-35115-0)).)

Comment: Right from the horses mouth.  very excellent.   My German is a little rusty

Comment: For English see his *Atomic structure and spectral lines* (1923, §VIII.2, [p. 470](https://archive.org/details/AtomicStructureAndSpectralLines/page/n243)), or Born ([1927](https://www.emis.de/cgi-bin/JFM-item?53.0876.01), [§33](https://archive.org/details/mechanicsoftheat029637mbp/page/n223)).